# Display multiple/multiline characters on Softkeyboard key

Tags: label, android-softkeyboard

> Hi i am working on **soft keyboard** where i need to display
>   **multiple/multiline characters on key**. Earlier i have implemented and
>   its working fine when i used just simple button's in linear layout and
>   for displaying multiline text on key as shown below

[image]

> As we can see i have **successfully displayed multiple characters on
>   button.** For that i have used

```
Button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='blue'><small><b>1</b></small></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color='red'><small><b>|</b></small></font><br /><big><font color='white'><b>q</b></font></big>");
```

> But since my keyboard must be worked as input service replacing
>   default device keyboard. So i have **used sample softkeyboard** given in
>   **android sdk.**
>
> But when i trying to set text as i set in above example it's not new
>   **line (<\br>) is not working** except this it is showing me output like
>   as shown below,

[image]

> As we can see my intended text is shown in key preview but failed to
>   display on key.

Comment: Can you provide the XML layout you're using the your 2nd example where it's not working?

Comment: hi @Whymarrh check this link i am sending here my xml layout  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9LGuVBIuz0HNExTal9NS19iNTQ/edit?usp=drive_web

Comment: Hi @Whymarrh have you seen my XML Layout, if yes you got any solution.